# How do I find a 'wide' variant of a font like Helvetica?

Tags: typography, font-recommendation

I need a wide font. It would be nice if it could resemble the text "YEARS" in the following image:

[image]

How can I find fonts like these?

Comment: You might want to search for 'Helvetica Extended' or similar. 'Extended' is the typography term for a 'wide' font. The opposite is 'condensed'.

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question to ask about wide fonts in general, so it no longer reads as a question to identify a font. If I overstepped, feel free to edit back!

Answer (score 1):

The nearest free font I could find was [Sui Generis](http://www.1001fonts.com/sui-generis-free-font.html): [image]